# Using awk in popen gives "runaway string constant" error

Tags: c, awk, quotes

The following line

```
FILE *fp=popen("ls -h --full-time | awk '{printf \" %-70s%-10s%-20s%-30s\n \", $9,$5,$6,$7}' ","r");
```

gives the error

> awk: Line 1 : runaway string constant "%-70s%-10....

I also tried

```
FILE *fp=popen("ls -h --full-time | awk \'{printf \" %-70s%-10s%-20s%-30s\n \", $9,$5,$6,$7}\' ","r");
```

Still the same error.

I know its got something to do with quotes. Only I can't figure out exactly what. How to get rid of the error? 
Thanks.

Comment: You should probably lose the space after the first `\"` and before the second one — especially the space before the second one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You meant for `awk` to interpret your `\n`, but in fact it's being interpreted by your C compiler as a literal newline. That's why awk sees a runaway string -- because by the time you've gotten there it's a literal newline.

You should use `\\n` in your original string.